# How to parse typesafe config with objects

Tags: typesafe, typesafe-config, typesafe-stack

I have a config `application.conf`:

```
usersHasPermissions = [
  {"login": "admin", "perms": ["p1", "p2"]},
  {"login": "petooh", "perms": ["p2"]},
  {"login": "*", "perms": ["p3"]}
]
```

How I can parse it to `Map[String,Set[String]`, where "login" - key, "perms" - set?

I can render it as json and parse. But I didn't want include json library in project. I think there is solution with `ConfigObject` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it's simple:

```
config.getObjectList("usersHasPermissions").asScala.map(o =>
      o.toConfig.getString("login") ->
        o.toConfig.getStringList("perms").asScala.toSet).toMap
```